# Android: DateUtils.formatDateTime change date and time sequence

Tags: android, date

I'm converting date into date and time string. I use following code:

```
String result = DateUtils.formatDateTime(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            millis,
            (DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | 
             DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | 
             DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE));
```

In result I get `14:17, 20.01.2013`. But I want to get `20.01.2013, 14:17`. I didn't found any flag to set sequence of date and time.

Is there easy way to convert date into localized string with format "[date], [time]"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't beleive DateUtils can do this. Consider using [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the user's Locale or your specific format `"dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"`.